# Will I lose out by not having grandchildren named after me?

Tags: death, names

Someone has a very strange Jewish name and he doesn't want to trouble his children to feel pressured to name their children after him when he passes away. He also feels bad that a grandchild should get stuck with his name. Can he tell his children that he doesn't want any of them to name grandchildren after him? Would he lose out in any way  (in the next world) ? Please provide authentic Jewish sources with your answer.

Comment: Wouldn't insisting that a grandchild be so tortured be the worse thing to do in terms of Shamayim-points?

Comment: Supposedly atteres chynka was named after a lady who refused to let her progeny be named after her once she was gone.

Comment: The question asks for sources that there will not be a loss, but who said there would be a benefit?... To name after a parent is just a honor -- if he demand not, רצונו זהו כבודו no?.. And even there could be an 'inyan' (again, sources?..), it would be very difficult to surpass a trouble for the child... בין אדם לחבירו is generally MUCH more than such subjects.... Did not put as an answer [if you want I can edit] because I have no precise sources, but for me it is totally obvious.

Comment: I myself should have been named after my grandfather, but his name (Ceasar) was deemed too odd by my parents so they instead that as my middle name.

But to echo @yO_, I think sources would first be needed to establish the assumption which this question is based on, that naming after someone benefits them in the world to come, and not merely an honorific or a cherished cultural tradition, which while valuable has no formal impact on a person's reward, punishment, and heavenly merit.

Comment: I have never heard that a person losses out if his name is not given to his descendants, the reason of the minhag to do it is not for the forefather but for the child (that the name should have a good effect on him and he would be similarly good as the forefather) or the parent (by calling his child in his forefathers he is honoring his forefather) but the forefathers name if continued but the birth of his descendants the name giveing has not conection

Comment: Why do you think the name of your decendet gives you something?

Comment: @hazoriz. Along the way, I've heard people saying that somehow it's a zchus for the neshama. That's part of what I'm trying to clarify through this question.